# What is the number permission for o+t in linux

Tags: linux, file-permissions

What is the number permission for o+t

It has to be close to 1755 but that's not right.

Using chmod o+t mydir. I get drwxrwsr-t

Using chmod 1755 mydir. I get d-wx-ws--t

I want to know what the number permissions are for o+t

Comment: what do you mean by `t`? o = others understood but what's t

Comment: `o+t` is a relative mode, and is equivalent to `+t` (it does not belong to u/g/o). It is equivalent to adding +1000. What you end up with depends on the previous mode of the file.

Comment: I wish people would comment why they are down ranking. How are new people going to get better at the site with no feedback? Also this is a good question! It might not be worded the best but I've looked everywhere for the answer.

Comment: It is not a good question, because it doesn't belong on stackoverflow: it is not about programming.

Comment: it is about programing... I am doing a perl chmod command and need to know the numbers that replicate the permissions of o+t. What part of chmod isn't programming lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple to find that out:

```
touch test
chmod 0000 test
chmod o+t test
stat test
```

... gives you: 1000 (octal)

Comment: Does it make a difference that this a directory because I can't seem to repeat your code.

Comment: Ya, it's 1000 for a file but a directory it's drwxrwsr-t but I don't know the numerical representation for that.

Comment: Check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal .. Once you got it, it is simple.